# На каком языке пишут iOS приложения Objective C или Swift?

Tags: ios

Я нашел пару обсуждений в которых говорилось о том, что первично был Objective C и уже сейчас Swift...

Если я новичок в iOS (есть опыт в андроиде) как понять с какого языка начать изучение iOS ? Или следует изучать их параллельно?

Swift это как Kotlin в Андроиде?

**Правка**

Как быть в такой ситуации.

У меня есть приложение на андроид и я хочу его выполнить на иос.

На каком языке начать писать с нуля?

Comment: Наверное стоит начать с Swift  и ограничится им. Obj-c хоть мне лично и ближе, в силу опыта, но используется он сейчас в основном для поддержки действующих проектов. Всё новое - Swift.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Objective C** — это вчера, **Swift** — это сегодня и завтра

Начинайте изучать **Swift**

Но стоит обратить внимание, часто ведь нужно поддерживать предыдущие приложения, а они могут быть написаны на **Objective C**

Comment: хаха)) В общем нужно и то и другое по хорошему знать)) Но что вы посоветуете если у меня есть приложение на андроид и мне с нуля нужно написать такое для иос ... На чем начинать писать?

Comment: Мы все новые приложения пишем на swift

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko: Пишите на Swift, разумеется.

Answer (score 2):

**Objective C** — это стабильность, много учебных материалов и большое комьюнити, **Swift** — это побаловаться в новыми замутами, отсутствие ABI stability и непойми что там они надумают завтра

Начинайте изучать **Objective C**

Но стоит обратить внимание, часто ведь нужно поддерживать приложения, написанные молодыми разработчиками, а они могут быть написаны на **Swift**

Comment: простите, не сдержался

Comment: Это универсальные ответы для любых вопросов с выбором !-)

Comment: хаха)) В общем нужно и то и другое по хорошему знать)) Но что вы посоветуете если у меня есть приложение на андроид и мне с нуля нужно написать такое для иос ... На чем начинать писать?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko: Пишите на Objective C, разумеется.

Comment: Как раз поспорю, новых учебных материалов уже на obj c  вы не найдете, все пишется на swift, и весь stack overflow решает проблемы на swift. Мы у себя все новое пишем на свифте

Comment: @Sander ну хотите abi stability обсудим :)

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko ну я и не утверждал что с этим все ок :)